# How to pass an extra parameter to authenticate function when using django.views.login?

Tags: python, django

I have an authentication back-end which looks like this

```
class Backend(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
            # Do stuff
```

My url handler looks like this

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

Login form looks something like this (standard form, you can skip this)

```
{% if not form.username.errors %}
        <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username (admin)" autofocus>
      {% else %}
        <div class="form-group has-error">
          {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <label class="control-label" for="id_username">{{ error }}</label>
          {% endfor %}
          <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username (admin)" autofocus>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if not form.password.errors %}
        <input id="id_password" name="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password (admin)" autofocus>
      {% else %}
        <div class="form-group has-error">
          {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <label class="control-label" for="id_password">{{ error }}</label>
          {% endfor %}
          <input id="id_password" name="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password (admin)">
        </div>
      {% endif %}
```

I need to pass an extra parameter(eg country) to the authenticate function possibly from the form. 
The new authenticate function should be like this

```
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, country=None):
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are asking about writing custom authentication backend and defining your own `authenticate` method in it.

Is so, check [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). As said there `authenticate` method is run against **authenticate(**credentials)**.
This means that you can pas any required kwargs parameters including 'country'.

In your case:

1. add 'country' to method declaration
2. pass country as an additional parameter when 'authenticate' user.

That is it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: How to pass the country from the form to authenticate function?

Comment: As said @Alasdair in answer below you should create (override) your custom form and pass it as an additional parameter in your `url.py` file. To pass that form in view add it to dictionary near your custom `template_name`

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass the `AuthenticationForm`, and override the `clean` method so that it calls `authenticate` with your extra parameter.

Then, in your urls.py, pass your `authentication_form` to the login view.